# On Button Click save Table Row and open another link with the saved ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

[image]

In the above image, I have a row, where data is added manually. I am looking for a solution which will allow me to do the following:

1. On click of config button save the entire row to the table.
2. Once saved read the inserted id and open another URL with that id in queryString.

So that means once the record is saved then it opens another where that inserted id is in query Sting to read the saved data into the newly opened page.

Is my above expectation possible ? If yes, then please guide the entire code.

The same need to done through: jquery, Ajax and PHP

Comment: Simple answer, yes that's possible.
However I don't think this is the place for someone else to write the code for you. You should at least show what you've got (if you have anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the `album,artist,year,origin,price an id` then  using jquery;

```
$("#buttonId").click(function(e){

  //pick all the row details
  var album = $(this).closest("tr").find("#albumId").text();
  var artist = $(this).closest("tr").find("#artistId").text();
  var year = $(this).closest("tr").find("#YearId").text();
  var origin = $(this).closest("tr").find("#OriginId").text();
  var price = $(this).closest("tr").find("#priceId").text();

  //use ajax to update a form with the values you want to save to the database
   $.ajax({
            url : "insert.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {"album":album, "artist":artist, "year":year, "origin":origin, "price":price},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(returnedId){
                //success code open a website with the id
                window.open("new_page.php?id="+returnedId');
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: You can create the insert.php page to accept and save the details to the db. i Have already given you 95% the remaining you can do it

Comment: i think they want to get some repo therefore posting this kind of questions.